# How to update/redraw the screen from within a button action event

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am just messing around trying to learn some iPhone development. I have a action function that responds to a button press. I am trying to generate a bunch of random colors and change the text color to make a sort of rainbow animation effect. I am missing the part that forces the text to redraw, just the last color change is shown.

```
- (IBAction)clearGreeting:(id)sender
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {

        // Generate random color
        float red = 0;
        float green = 0;
        float blue = 0;
        float alpha = 0;

        red = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        green = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        blue = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        alpha = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;

        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
        // need something here to update the display
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
    }
}
```

From similar questions on SO and forums, I tries things like [self.view reloadInputViews] but it is not doing what I mean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try, `[view setNeedsDisplay]` or `[view setNeedsDisplayInRect:]`.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, you can't do animation that way because the iPhone screen is only redrawn once every 60th of a second when the event loop fires and a tight loop like a for loop will just block the main thread and stop the event loop from updating until it has finished.

Instead you need to do your drawing code using a timer or display link so that it only draws one frame at a time and allows the event loop to update in between. The timer version is easiest to understand:

```
- (IBAction)clearGreeting:(id)sender
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)update
{
    // Generate random color
    float red = 0;
    float green = 0;
    float blue = 0;
    float alpha = 0;

    red = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    green = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    blue = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    alpha = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;

    self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}
```

To make the animation run slower, change the 1.0/60.0 (60 frames per second) to something like 1.0/10.0 (10 frames per second).